# Updating Product Count using Plus, Minus button without refreshing page JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

How can I update product Count in a custom PHP shopping cart that I am working on,  using Plus, Minus button without refreshing page?

I would like to add or delete quantity without reloading page.

My products in the cart are listed as below.

```
Burger $3.99
Pasta Bowl $8.99
```

I would like to have a image button to increase or decrease the quantity like below. The option to increase and decrease should display when you click on the plus or minus sign.

```
1 Burger $3.99
2 Pasta Bowl $17.98
```

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: use ajax to achieve this

Comment: How? Any sample code?

Comment: What is the base code that you have.  Use jQuery and Ajax.

Comment: @RajK https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As webgal suggested, AJAX is the way forward. Have the plus/minus buttons calling a function, say `updateQuantity(direction)` where direction is up or down (depending on the button clicked. So, the plus button will call `updateQuantity(1)` and the minus button will call `updateQuantity(-1)` and use that value to manipulate the object's quantity in the cart.

Simple AJAX code (which you'll simply need to tailor to your own need) will be as follows:

```
function updateQuantity(direction){
   var xmlhttp;

   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // For new browsers and IE7+
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log('created XMLHttpRequest');
   }else{
        // For old IE versions (volatile)
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        console.log('created ActiveXObject');
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
       if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
           //if the AJAX call is finished and the HTTP status is 200 (OK)
           console.log('response received');
           var e = document.getElementById('theElementYouWantToChange');
           e.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }else if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status!=200){
       //second if condition specified, else the console will log an error
       //whenever the readystate changes, and this happens 3 times during
       //an acceptable AJAX call    
           console.log("Error retrieving search response. Status: "+xmlhttp.status);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/updateCart.php?product="+productID+"&change="+direction,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

You will need to set up the variable productID which attaches to the product you are modifying the quantity of

Comment: Thanks James. I got good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#plus').click(function(){
  $.get('yourphpfile?val=value_to_increment', function(data){
    //code to update your html. 
    //data variable will hold whatever you echo from php.
    //it's considering only simple use, you can use JSON for more complex operations.
  });
});
```

basically all you have to do is create an event on click on image (one for each button)
then pass the value to the php server/file with the data to be updated from server and in the callback function you just have to update the dom (your html) using the data provided by the php code.